# Catch block is not executing on DataIntegrityViolationException in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

```
try {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(language);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception");
    }
```

When I try to delete a language(object) through hibernate, the exception in thrown but catch block is not executed.

This is the error log

```
Hibernate: select language0_.id as id1_9_0_, language0_.created_date as created_2_9_0_, language0_.image as image3_9_0_, language0_.language as language4_9_0_, language0_.nickname as nickname5_9_0_, language0_.remark as remark6_9_0_, language0_.status as status7_9_0_, language0_.updated_date as updated_8_9_0_ from db.language language0_ where language0_.id=?
Hibernate: delete from db.language where id=?

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`movie`, CONSTRAINT `fk_movie_language` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: can you add more details, some logs would be great help

Comment: Well no it won't. The actual delete happens when the transaction commits and that is, I suspect, as soon as the method containing this code finishes completion.

Comment: which hibernate version are you using ... and do you use any special kind of  session / sessionfactory?

Comment: have you tried  `System.err.println("exception");`